# boost ptr_container leak on 'release'?

Tags: c++, boost, valgrind, boost-ptr-container

I'm assuming that an object that's released from a `ptr_set` is leaked if it's not manually deleted. However, the test program below only shows 2 leaks in valgrind (from lines 9/13), and no leak for line 12. Have I misunderstood `release`, or is `ptr_container` managing to clean up somehow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_set.hpp>

typedef boost::ptr_set<int> SetInt;

int main() {
   SetInt s;

   new int(1);                // leak, reported by valgrind

   s.insert(new int(2));
   s.insert(new int(3));      // leak? not reported by valgrind
   s.insert(new int(4));      // leak, reported by valgrind

   s.erase(s.begin());
   s.release(s.begin());      // release '3'

   SetInt::auto_type old_int1 = s.release(s.begin());
   int *old_int2 = old_int1.release();
   std::cout << '\'' << *old_int2 << "' has been released\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'4' has been released
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor of 3 is indeed called just as you observed. The reason is that s.release returns a smart pointer which will delete the object when that pointer goes out of scope. So, your line:

```
s.release(s.begin());      // release '3'
```

is similar to writing

```
{    
   SetInt::auto_type tmp= s.release(s.begin());      // release '3'
} // at this point the '3' is destroyed.
```

Object 4 is not destructed because you tell your smart pointer old_int1 not to do it.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#new-functions